# How does GA4 determine language?

Tags: google-analytics

In GA4, there's an item that is `User attributes>Overview>Users by Language` as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

How does GA4 determine the language?  Is it:

1. Language setting of user's their operating system?
2. Language setting of user's web browser?
3. Language specified in a specific HTML tag on the web page?
4. Primary language of the user's physical geographic location?
5. other??? If other, please specify

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user browser visits a page, it sends a special header called **Accept Language**. It basically tells the webpage which languages the user understands or wants the information to be displayed preferably in that language.

Note that it can send multiple languages, as to signal in which order the user prefers to see the information. If it isn't available, show the next one in the list. For example, my browser sends 4 language preferences:

- English US
- English
- Spanish Latam
- Spanish

The user can manually add /remove languages or change the preference order in the config settings of the browser.